# Is there a way to have a domain substituted in for urls in the html page?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

For urls in a .razor page, I can do `src="~/images/icons/arrow.svg"` and that turn it into a url to that file in the app.

However, I am going to put all these images up in Azure BLOB storage. The domain for that should stay constant. But, in case it changes, is there a way to do something like `src="@/images/icons/arrow.svg"` where I define `@` to be `MyDomain.blob.core.windows.net/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also define a service and inject it inside the _Imports.razor file and then you could use it in any component.

Details, you could refer to below codes:

Service class:

```
public  class ImageUrlService
{
    public   string BaseImageUrl { get; } = "https://yourstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/";
}
```

Program.cs codes:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ImageUrlService>();
```

_Imports.razor codes:

```
@inject ImageUrlService ImageUrlService
```

Component codes:

```
<img src="@($"{ImageUrlUtility.BaseImageUrl}images/icons/arrow.svg")" alt="Arrow" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yup.

Put the configured domain in your appsettings:

```
{
  "BlobStorage": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://MyDomain.blob.core.windows.net/"
  },
}
```

Inject IConfiguration into your razor page:

```
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
```

Then use the value in an interpolated string:

```
<img src="@($"{Configuration["BlobStorage:BaseUrl"]}images/icons/arrow.svg")" />
```

Comment: thank you - good suggestion and useful for other situations too.

Comment: Especially useful if you want to use different base addresses, depending on environment, e.g. Dev, Test, Prod, etc. without changing your code.